# django 1.3 template tag url unexpected result

Tags: django, templates, url, templatetag

template:

```
            <!-- Images slide as a row starts -->
            <!-- power.views.IMAGE_SLIDES_ROW returns image_slider_row/   -->
            {% url power.views.IMAGE_SLIDES_ROW %} 
            <!-- Images as a row Ends -->
```

url conf:

```
     url(r'^image_slider_row/', views.images_slider_row_func, name='image_slider_row'),
```

View :

```
def images_slider_row(request):
    print "Debug-1"
    return render_to_response('images_slider_row.html', {})
```

actually I am expecting **"images_slider_row_func"** will get call on url tag execution but it is not happening, it is showing following string in the browser

> **/images_slider_row/**

am I missing anything or am I misunderstood the concept?
Please help me for fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `url` method takes the parameters for the regular expression matching the accessed URL, the function to call (in this case, images_slider_row_func) and with the keyword arg `name` the name that can be used as shown in your template to identify that function when calling the url "macro".

However, django should try to access the function "images_slider_row_func" when accessing the URL "/images_slider_row/" (notice the difference here!)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a href="{% url image_slider_row %}">foo bar</a>` for your example,
templatetag `url` expect `name` argument from you `urls.py`

Comment: Yes I have tried this anchor tag, even I have added the name arg in urls.py. when I click on this link I am able to see the image slider getting render in the browser but my expected result is if I use url template tag it should keep the image slider where ever I place just like include tag, but if we use include tag which means tightly coupled. I am trying to make it independent.